# Adding elements of RGB array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, rgb

Say I have a 2D RGB array that is show as:

```
[[[ 0.    0.   0.5]
  [ 0.5   0.   0.5]
  [ 0.    0.   0.5]
  ..., 
  [ 0.5   0.   0.5]
  [ 0.    0.   0.5]
  [ 0.    0.   0.5]]]
```

I want to add the individual elements in the `R` and `B` columns to the `G` part of the array so it looks like:

```
[[[ 0.    0.5   0.5]
  [ 0.5   1.0   0.5]
  [ 0.    0.5   0.5]
  ..., 
  [ 0.5   1.0   0.5]
  [ 0.    0.5   0.5]
  [ 0.    0.5   0.5]]]
```

What would be the easiest way to approach this problem?

Comment: That looks like 3D to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
arr[...,1] = arr[...,0] + arr[...,2]
```

or perhaps more readably,

```
R, G, B = arr[...,0], arr[...,1], arr[...,2]
G[:] = R + B
```

Since `G` is a basic slice of `arr`, it is a view. Modifying a view modifies the original array.  The
assignment `G[:] = ...` modifies `G` inplace. So the assignment modifies `arr`.

---

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[ 0.,    0.,   0.5],
                 [ 0.5,   0.,   0.5],
                 [ 0.,    0.,   0.5],
                 [ 0.5,   0.,   0.5],
                 [ 0.,    0.,   0.5],
                 [ 0.,    0.,   0.5]]])

R, G, B = arr[...,0], arr[...,1], arr[...,2]
G[:] = R + B

print(arr)
```

yields

```
[[[ 0.   0.5  0.5]
  [ 0.5  1.   0.5]
  [ 0.   0.5  0.5]
  [ 0.5  1.   0.5]
  [ 0.   0.5  0.5]
  [ 0.   0.5  0.5]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would convert your list of lists in an [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), and then slice it.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5],
            [ 0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
            [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5]])
a[:,1] += a[:,0] + a[:,2]
print(a)
```

Output :

```
array([[ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  1. ,  0.5],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5]])
```